# Передача this в конструктор базового класа или члена

Tags: c++

Почему не рекомендуется использовать **this** при вызове конструктора базового класса, или конструктора члена класса?

например:

```
class Derived;

class Base
{
public:
    Base(Derived *pBuzz);
};

class Derived
    : Base
{
public:
    Derived()
        : Base(this) /* warning */
    { }
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Потому что в момент выполнения конструктора базового класса или члена класса объект класса Derived ещё не создан (его конструктор не начал выполнение), а, значит, попытка обратиться к полям и методам класса Derived может привести к неопределённому поведению. Но если такого обращения не производится, то всё в порядке. 
В параграфе 12.6.2/7 стандарта C++ нашлось разрешение использовать this таким образом, так что warning можно отключать спокойно.

Comment: Ясно. Я ожидал, что причины будут более серьезны.
Конкретно в моём случае, указатель на производный класс нужен для инициализации ссылки на него в базовом классе.

Answer (score 2):

> Ясно. Я ожидал, что причины будут более серьезны. Конкретно в моём случае, указатель на производный класс нужен для инициализации ссылки на него в базовом классе.

Я бы сказал, что это ошибка проектирования иерархии классов. Скажите зачем вам понадобилось так делать и я отвечу почему так нельзя делать.